# Reading the clob data into flat file using shell scripting in UNIX

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, clob

I am reading the multiple clob data records from DB into file in UNIX using the shell scrpiting.

CLOB1:-

COUNTRY

AUSTR

CLOB2:-

ALIA

WON THE

CLOB3:-

WORLCUP

THRICE

Query fetched the clob like as below. When word is continued in next clob there is a single new line character(ex: between clob1 ending and clob2 starting) . When the word is not continued in the next clob there are 2 new line characters(ex:- between clob2 ending and clob3 starting).

Actual output after fetching the data from clob using select statement:-

COUNTRY

AUST

ALIA

WON THE

WORLCUP

THRICE

I want to modify the output file as  per the  below format. Can someone help me in this ?

COUNTRY

AUSTRALIA

WON THE

WORLDCUP

THRICE

Comment: What DB? Where are you going to recover the missing R in AUSTRALIA from?

Comment: Sorry..Earlier it's a typo where R is missed.

Comment: Below are the statements called inside script.                 sqlplus -s $DATABASE << EOF >>CLOB3.txt
select clob from testtable where country='AUSTRALIA';
exit; 
EOF

Comment: the script belongs in your question. Learn to use the `{}` formatting tool at the top left of the edit box. Select code to be formatted as then click `{}`, then Save your changes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to process the following file:

```
COUNTRY

AUSTR
ALIA

WON THE

WORLCUP

THRICE
```

to get:

```
COUNTRY
AUSTRALIA
WON THE
WORLCUP
THRICE
```

If so, use this command:

```
perl -lp00e 'y/\n//d' CLOB3.txt
```